# The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Interop.IVsDataProviderManager service could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, linq, solution-explorer

I'm using VS2008 to develop an app. Now, whenever I connect to database in Server Explorer, it shows me the report

> The
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Interop.IVsDataProviderManager
>   service could not be found.

And whenever I'm trying to Open my LINQ Datacontext in APP_CODE in Solution Explorer, it alerts a pop up msg which says

> Visual Studio 
>  Unexpected Error

Can anyone help me so solve this problem please, thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just goto start -> Run -> type devenv /ResetSkipPkgs

This solved my problem.

Happy Programming....................

Mohan

Answer (score 2):

It is the services missing error. It's very easy to resolve; just go to `TOOLS` options and select the `OPTIONS` check the `AUTO RECOVER` option. It may be solved

Answer (score 0):

If All those points above not worked ...try to reinstall your .NET Framework or install .net Framework 4.5.2

Regards